# How to input the model field as a string (undefined method `b' for :title:Symbol)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im using the [IMDB gem](https://github.com/ariejan/imdb). To do a search with it, you need

```
movie_list = Imdb::Search.new("title as a string")
```

In my application, I use a form to take in a movie title and save it as a field in the model table. I want to use the value :title for the search.

When I do

```
movie_list = Imdb::Search.new(:title)
```

I get the error, "undefined method `b' for :title:Symbol"

Is this correct?

```
movie_list = Imdb::Search.new("{#{:title})
```

Here is how I use the code:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :actors, dependent: :destroy
    after_create :fill_actors_table
    validates_presence_of :title

    def fill_actors_table
       # can't figure out how to insert string. :title
       # "Lion King works"  
       movie_list = Imdb::Search.new("Finding Nemo")
       new_movie = movie_list.movies.first
      id = new_movie.id

      i = Imdb::Movie.new("#{id}")
      i.cast_members.each do |actor_name|
        actor_image = Google::Search::Image.new(:query => actor_name).first
        actor_image_url = actor_image.uri
        Actor.create(:name => actor_name, :file => actor_image_url)
      end
    end
```

Comment: Can you post some more of your code? Especially where you have methods/objects/symbols names `b`.

Comment: @HunterStevens I don't at all! That's why I'm so confused.

Answer (score 3):

`:title` is a symbol. It has no other meaning except being a symbol with value `:title`. The initializer expect you to pass a string.

Assuming you are fetching the parameter from a request, you probably want to use `params[:title]`.

```
movie_list = Imdb::Search.new(params[:title])
```

As a side note, you may also want to have a look at some basic Ruby documentation and books before proceeding. It looks like you're very new to it.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, I am very new to rails. I have a few years of other programming and have been trying to jump right into a project. I learn a lot better this way than just straight reading the documentation. Clearly I need to do a better job of reading more carefully though. Thanks. I let myself get confused by the b appearing.